# observing memory allocation in Xcode Ansi C

Tags: c, xcode, memory, input, memory-leaks

I want to observe the dynamically allocated memory in a C program while running, and to detect memory leaks. My program allocates memory according to user input. I'm looking for hours now for tutorials that might help, but the thing is that all of what i've found is not based on user input! i want to insert input and run the "instruments" in the same time..any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: i can but it doesn't really matter..the code has a binary tree and every leaf is allocated dynamically according to the user input, and of course there are also static arrays and so on

Comment: Make a printout of entire memory/tree content after every tree operation.

Comment: sorry don't understand it..can you pls be more specific?

Comment: You can use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH1-SW1) to assist in hunting down memory leaks on your mac app. It should have come with your Xcode distribution install.

Comment: it does, but when i use instrument through Xcode or even just through utilities, it does not react to the input. I open instruments with "memory leaks" and it just start recording, and shows nothing..

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you watch WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242). It gives excellent primer on types of memory, issues that can arise, coding conventions to watch out for, how to use Instruments to identify issues, etc. It's a good place to start.

Lots of leaks cannot be identified by the "Leaks" tool in Instruments. Check out the "Allocations" tool and some of the great features hidden in there such as heapshots (discussed in that video) or <kbd>option</kbd>-dragging in the Allocations tool graph. Also, make sure you avail yourself of the static analyzer ("Analyze" on the "Product" menu in Xcode, or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) which can identify a remarkable number of issues just by analyzing at your code.

Comment: +1 I was not aware the static analyzer was so thorough. Just for the hell of it I threw what I thought were some pretty subtle bugs at mine, and was shocked how well it identified most of them.